# SilverStripe Behat throwing error: Call to a member function manage() on null (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)

Tags: unit-testing, silverstripe, behat, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. I am writing Behavioural Tests for my application using Behat. But I am getting an error in the console when I run the tests. Following is how I set up Behat for my project.

I created a feature file with the following definition

```
Feature: ls
    In order to see the directory structure
    As a UNIX user
    I need to be able to list the current directory's contents

    Scenario: List 2 files in a directory
        Given I am in a directory "test"
        And I have a file named "foo"
        And I have a file named "bar"
        When I run "ls"
        Then I should get:
            """
            bar
            foo
            """
```

This is my test class

```
class FeatureContext extends SilverStripeContext
{
    /**
     * @Given I am in a directory :arg1
     */
    public function iAmInADirectory($arg1)
    {
        return new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @Given I have a file named :arg1
     */
    public function iHaveAFileNamed($arg1)
    {
        return new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @When I run :arg1
     */
    public function iRun($arg1)
    {
        return new PendingException();
    }

    /**
     * @Then I should get:
     */
    public function iShouldGet(PyStringNode $string)
    {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

When I run the tests, I got the following complain in the console.

```
 ┌─ @BeforeScenario # SilverStripe\Framework\Tests\Behaviour\FeatureContext::before()
  │
  ╳  Fatal error: Call to a member function manage() on null (Behat\Testwork\Call\Exception\FatalThrowableError)
  │
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I get rid of that error?